# Force 64-bit Java in OS X

Tags: java, macos, 64-bit

It used to be that (when Java wasn't handled by Apple for our systems) there was a list in the control panel that let you choose which version of Java was preferred. That doesn't really exist anymore as far as I can tell.

By the way it looks it's either handled in JavaApplicationStub or the info.plist in the application bundle. I'm helping out a game developer who doesn't do much Mac stuff, and previously this hasn't really been important but now it is.

I'm looking for the exact lines I'd need to add to said files (assuming, of course, I'm interpreting the info right).

I've done as much searching as I can, but all I can find is an old Mac help file from 2005 or so (which is actually about the reverse, forcing a program to use 32-bit) and some stuff for Minecraft that recommended the old method. I've also tried searching Stack Overflow with no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated. Also, this is my first time posting on SO so if I've made any errors in my post please point them out to me. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

I need it to run in 64-bit because in 32-bit it's causing some out of memory errors. The specifics aren't particularly necessary- what's important is that it does need to run in 64-bit. It's not a problem that's going to go away if it stays on 32, and we'd rather have it 64 in the long term due to slightly better performance anyways.

Comment: Why do you need to force 64 bit java?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about something like java -d64 ?

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
```

with app bundle, add this to Info.plist before the MainClass key:

```
    <dict>
    <key>VMOptions</key>
    <string>-d64</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response- would that be into the JavaApplicationStub? Right now all I have is the compiled version, but I should be able to get ahold of the original file (I'm assuming it is compiled). Also, I should clarify, I can mostly read Java but not write it. I'm more of a writer/developer than a coder (and I'm just volunteering to help on the project I'm asking about, not affiliated with the team at all).

Comment: To further clarify/query: It's normally shipped with .bats that let it work on either 32-bit or 64-bit architectures for Windows. I'm assuming that means there's no additional work that needs to be done for it to function in 64-bit on OS X other than adding the correct flag in the correct location? And as a bonus question, do .bat files accomplish the same thing as info.plist does for OS X, or is it more similar to the JavaApplicationStub (in this specific example, at least)? I'm aware .bat files are generally the equivalent of shell scrips.

Comment: I'm curious why you have go to 64bit since in most case 32 bit is sufficient.
if a shell script (.sh) works for you, it could be a easy fix, just add -d64 to the command line.
I'm not familiar with JavaApplicationStub..though. there should be a way to specific it in somewhere.

Comment: Long story short the game is causing out of memory errors on 32-bit architectures right now. It's not **really** a long term problem, but it's something I'm trying to get sorted in the interim. The game gets launched via application bundle, not .sh at the moment so that's somewhat off the table. By my understanding, though, that can be handled within the info.plist- I just don't know what to add and where. It could also be handled by JavaApplicationStub, which is where OSX gets some of the launch parameters from as I understand. http://informagen.com/JarBundler/StubFile.html

Comment: Just noticed your edit. I now get "You can't open the application "App Name" because it may be damaged or incomplete." Any ideas? I appreciate your help, by the way.

Comment: I think you didn't edit it properly? can you make sure the XML is wellformed? Note the VMOptions comes in the second level of dict, right before the MainClass line.

Answer (score 0):

See [these instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) for packaging Java 7 with your OS X application bundle.  Java 7 on OS X is 64-bit only.  This is now the preferred way to package Java apps on OS X and the only way the Mac Store accepts them.